# SQL statement to retrieve several Counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
table account:
    acID (pri, uni, a-i)
    ...

table patient:
    paID (pri, uni, a-i)
    paAccountID (int, foreign key)
    ...

table test:
    tsID (pri, uni, a-i)
    tsAccountID (int, foreign key)
    tsPatientID (int, foreign key)
    tsStatus (int, ranges 0 to 3)
    tsFlag (int, ranges 0 to 1)
```

Retrieving data from `patient` and number of `tsID` for each patient:

```
SELECT patient.*, Count(tsID) as tsCount   
FROM account 
LEFT JOIN patient ON acID = paAccountID
LEFT JOIN test ON paID = tsPatientID
WHERE paAccountID=1
GROUP BY paID
```

Now, I would like to retrieve number of `tsFlag=1`, number of `tsStatus=0`, number of 'tsStatus=1' ... number of `tsStatus=3`.

Thanks to Explosion Pill's answer:

```
SELECT patient.*, Count(tsID), SUM(tsStatus=0), 
SUM(tsStatus=1), SUM(tsStatus=2), SUM(tsStatus=3), SUM(tsFlag=1)
FROM account 
LEFT JOIN patient ON acID = paAccountID
LEFT JOIN test ON paID = tsPatientID
WHERE paAccountID=1
GROUP BY paID
```

Is working like a charm, BUT giving `NULL` for the `SUM` if the `Count=0`
- how can I get `0` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the count of X = Y by using a `SUM`:

```
SELECT patient.*, SUM(tsStatus = 1) AS tsStatus1
FROM ...
```

You can do this for the other columns as well.

You can use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` to specify a default non-null value:

```
IFNULL(SUM(tsStatus = 3), 0);
```

Comment: In Mysql `sum(tsStatus = 1)` is fine too